# Geth RPC eth_getTransactionReceipt method

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions

Geth RPC docs:

**eth_getTransactionReceipt**

Returns the receipt of a transaction by transaction hash.

**Note** *That the receipt is not available for pending transactions.*

What is the reason why Receipt not available for pending transactions?

Answer (score 1):

A Transaction receipt gives data about the state after the transaction is mined, the hash of the trie which stores these receipts is included in the block headers. If you want to check the details of a pending transaction, then you can use `eth_getTransaction` method.

Comment: I need details about script that call to contract. In case Receipt, I can parse log messages and get information (at example about token transfers on ERC 20). Unconfirmed transaction also should be parsed is any other way then code own script parser?

Comment: Sounds like `eth_call` might be useful in your case